# Confusion in Choosing between Trigger or Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two SQL Server 2008 running in my network say Server1 and Server2.

I have a web app running that operates on Server1. I have similar tables in Server2.

Now what I need to do is to update or insert the data in Server2 as it is inserted in Server1 by my Application.

I m in a confusion whether to write Triggers on tables in Server1 or modify my Procedures in Server1 to achieve the same.

Thank You.

Regards,

```
   DnshPly9
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out SQL Server replication:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Before you decide on replication technique you would probably benefit from reading this piece which guides you through the different considerations you have to make in different replication scenarios.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565.aspx

Comment: The tables in Server2 have a few same/common columns in tables, not all. say col1,col2,col3 in Server1 and i would like to insert col1 and col2 in Server2 ignoring col3. So i am looking for either trigger or procedure.

Comment: SSIS (previously known as DTS) should be able to handle this easily. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: Actually I am working with only 2 servers, so I think using Trigger or a stored procedure will do it for me. What if i only need to go either using Trigger or Chaning my already written procedures to include another insert(or any) query to insert(or any) the data???